# なさい and ください using い-stem instead of う-stem

Tags: etymology, conjugations, subsidiary-verbs, auxiliaries

I'm curious as to why these two verbs use their い-stem, instead of う like ます does after the い-stem and くれる/あげる/おく do after the て form. (I know the two are *aru* special class verbs.) Does this have to do with 有り/なり using い by default back then, or is it more about roundabout formal speech?

Comment: I don’t quite understand your question but are these related by any chance?: [Why does くださる have an irregular infinitive form (ください)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42921/43676), [Proper form of なさる - なさります or なさいます](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32700/43676)

Comment: Phrased differently, the questions would be: if all other auxiliaries and conjugations use the 終止形 by default, why do くださる and なさる use the 連用形 exclusively?

Comment: They don't use 連用形 exclusively. If you read one of the links above, you should know なさい and ください are "command" forms (albeit irregular ones).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment section, くださる and なさる are irregular verbs in Japanese. The regular **imperative** form くだされ/なされ somehow changed to ください/なさい long ago, making them look identical to the pre-masu form.

The れ version still exists, but sounds fairly old. You can hear samurai and old sage say 見なされ or 見てくだされ in fictional works.

See also: [Proper form of なさる - なさります or なさいます](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32700/5010)