# Why the ます形 of おっしゃる is おっしゃいます?

Tags: words, conjugations

I'm studying for the N4 of the JLPT and in the 尊敬語 lesson is the verb おっしゃる

おっしゃる is the respectful form of 言う. When in the textbook they change the verb to the ます形 it changes in a way that I can not understand.

How I understand it should be

> おっしゃる ► Ends in "る" so the "い" sound of that character is "り" ► おっしゃり ► and
>   then we add the ます ► **おっしゃります**

How it is in the textbook:

> おっしゃる ► おっしゃいます

The same happens with

> くださる ► くださいます
>
> なさる ► なさいます
>
> いらっしゃる ► いらっしゃいます

Does someone knows why it is like this?

Comment: 『イ[音便]{おんびん}』・・・・ eg [書]{か}く→書**い**た 　https://kotobank.jp/word/イ音便-430840

Comment: Related, maybe?: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32700/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24033/9831

Comment: Despite what people might be taught, not all verbs neatly fit into the 3 classes that are usually listed. Typically in J-E dictionaries, these will be listed as "special class". See: http://jisho.org/word/%E4%BB%B0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%97%E3%82%83%E3%82%8B

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough, 仰有る【おっしゃる】/ 仰る 【おっしゃる】 is an irregular verb :) there is a bit more irregular verbs in Japanese than the classicals する or 来る。

There is a nice [list of irregular verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_irregular_verbs) on Wikipedia