# What is the difference between the imperative forms of the -aru verbs?

Tags: grammar, usage, verbs, imperatives

What is the difference between these imperative forms:

nas-**ai**

nas-**are**

nas-**aimase**

nas-**aimashi**

(As far as I understand these verb forms apply only to the honorific –aru verbs *irassharu, ossharu, kudasaru, gozaru* and *nasaru*, or am I mistaken?)

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32706/7810

Comment: So, the difference is stylistic and is not related to the meaning in any way (adding nuances, etc.). I’d appreciate it if someone could give me a hint on how these four forms came about (e.g. from different dialects, sound changes and reduction over time, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

nasai and nasaimase are イ音便 forms for nasare and nasarimase.
nasaimashi is an uncommon alternative for nasaimase.
nasai and nasaimase are different in that mase is more formal (for a customer perhaps) and might give a kind of refined air to it in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could hear nasai and rarely nasaimase in formal situations but won't nasare and nasaimasi. The latter two are archaic.