# Confusion on imperative forms?

Tags: conjugations, imperatives

I have heard of all of the following conjugations as being imperative forms in Japanese by various texts.

> なさる　→　なさい
>
> くださる　→　ください
>
> いらっしゃる　→　いらっしゃいませ

Are these all part of the same category of imperative forms? If so, are these irregular conjugations and/or are they distinct from the 「止まれ」-style imperative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are irregular conjugations.  Copying from [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8D%E8%A6%8F%E5%89%87%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E):

> ござる・為さる（なさる）・下さる（くださる）・いらっしゃる・おっしゃるの5語は助動詞「ます」に続く時の連用形が「〜い」となる点が通常の五段活用動詞と異なる。**「ござる」以外は命令形も「〜い」となる**。規則どおりの「ござります」「なさります」などは、古風な響きとなる。

There is a sound shift to using い for both the 連用形 (masu-form) as well for the imperative form. As Wikipedia mentions, using the "correct" form sounds very old fashioned.

Here's another question about this:

- [Proper form of なさる - なさります or なさいます](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32700/proper-form-of-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99-or-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99)